Is there a notification that shows how much time is left before Google Family Link will block the app?
Seems like I remember Family Link would warn before blocking at end of time limit.
Now it blocks the app without prior warning or notification,  which is distressing and often initiates an emotional rift between parent and child...
Would love to find a way to notify child of time limit remaining fromwithin the Family Link app.
I have seen alternate apps to help with notifications,  but would rather Google fix the Family Link.
